# Is it possible to hide the histogram in Darktable?

Tags: darktable, histogram

In the darkroom section of darktable, the histogram takes up a huge amount of vertical space.  Is there any way to hide or move it?

Comment: It's not just the histogram, but if you hit <Tab>, it hides all the top/bottom/side bars...

Comment: Thanks @twalberg.  Unfortunately this won't quite work for my situation, as what I am ultimately looking for is more space for the modules.

Comment: You may want to comment on [this github issue](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/2041), where the size of the histogram is being discussed (among other things).

Comment: Thanks for the link @junkyardsparkle.  I added this as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Darkroom 3.0 and ctrl-shft-h seems to do the trick.